# Issues when calling vcount in orgtbl

Tags: calc, orgtbl

This is a minimal orgtbl example with no problem:

```
|---|
| a |
| b |
|---|
| 2 |
```

#+TBLFM: @>$1=vcount(@<..@>>)

But if I insert some particular chars (dot, comma, ...) the result or vcount is #error

```
|--------|
| a.     |
| b      |
|--------|
| #ERROR |

#+TBLFM: @>$1=vcount(@<..@>>)
```

I do not understand why. Is this a bug or a feature ?

Comment: Try `C-c {` and reevaluate to see what's happening. Almost certainly a bug, but there are all sorts of little gotchas like this in the `org-table-recalculate` code: try e.g. quoting the entries - it does not work but there is no error.

Comment: It seems to me that the vector functions (vcount, vsum, vmean ...) are intended for numeric data and only for them.
I tried to work around the problem by fetching a column by org-table-get-range, but there are comparable problems and the result is only unreliable.

Comment: The best way I've found to deal with problems like this is to forego Calc functions and use Lisp formulas: something like `#+TBLFM: @>$1='(length (list @<$1..@>>$1))` perhaps. There are still problems but I find the results more predictable.

Comment: That is a nice idea. I was not aware of the syntax (list <range>). Many thanks.